# How to check if a string contains specific words in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check whether string contain specific given sentence in string or not. I have below string in that I want to check `'already registered'` sentence present or not however string is contain array so I couldn't get.

```
message =  'User error fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"Registration of \'yandgsub15\' failed: Identity \'yandgsub15\' is already registered"}]]' }
```

I tried below function, however I couldn't get it though it. please anybody have solution?

```
var n = error.includes("registered");
```

Comment: message.indexOf("already registered") >= 0

Comment: You used the incorrect variable to get your expected result. Try to change `error` to `message`. `var n = message.includes("registered");`

Comment: your string name is 'message' but you're searching your word in a string named error, your first real problem is here

Comment: right I forget to do it like  const message = error.message

Comment: var n = message.includes("registered");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to search for "registered" in a string called error but there isn't try this:

```
message =  'User error fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"Registration of \'yandgsub15\' failed: Identity \'yandgsub15\' is already registered"}]]' }

var n = message.includes("registered");
```

Comment: right I forget to do it like const message = error.message

Answer (score 2):

I think you just don't search on the good variable

In your example you're trying to search `"registered"` on `error` and not on `message`

The code below is working

```
message = 'User error fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"Registration of \'yandgsub15\' failed: Identity \'yandgsub15\' is already registered"}]]' 

var n = message.includes('registered')

console.log(n) // true
```